# configure: error: "freeradius headers not found"

Tags: linux, protocol-buffers, radius, freeradius

I am getting following config error while installing some package. I am using ubantu 64 bit machine and have installed free radius package but error still persists.

```
 $:/tmp/rlm_protobuf-freeradius-2.1.x$ sudo ./configure
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for curl-config... /usr/bin/curl-config
checking for curl >= 7.18.2... yes
checking CURL_CFLAGS...
checking CURL_LIBS... -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcurl -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking freeradius-devel/radius.h usability... no
checking freeradius-devel/radius.h presence... no
checking for freeradius-devel/radius.h... no
checking freeradius-devel/radiusd.h usability... no
checking freeradius-devel/radiusd.h presence... no
checking for freeradius-devel/radiusd.h... no
configure: error: "freeradius headers not found"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing libfreeradius-dev package from repositories.

Comment: Thnaks, for the reply but libfreeradius-dev package is available......     # apt-get install libfreeradius-dev
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    libfreeradius-dev is already the newest version.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 617 not upgraded.

Comment: If you are able to locate the headers yourself, you can add the directories to one (or all) of the following environment variables:   CPATH, C_INCLUDE_PATH, CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH, OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH.

Answer (score 0):

The autoconf script is meant to be used for modules located in the src/modules/ directory of the FreeRADIUS source tree. For it to work correctly you should move rlm_protobuf into src/modules/ and then run the main FreeRADIUS configure script.